# Need help on this List logic not sure how to write?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, lambda

I have two list, i could like to avoid a index and i need to achive the below function in lambda

```
List<object> List1 = new List<object>()

List<object> List2 = new List<object>()

List1.Add(new Someclass1().someFunction1(3));
List1.Add(new Someclass1().someFunction1(4));

List2.Add(new Someclass1().someFunction1(3));
List2.Add(new Someclass1().someFunction1(4));

//currently i'm doing like this below  
await  List1[0].somemethod(logger, List2[0]);  // i could like to avoid index 
await  List1[1].somemethod(logger, List2[0]);
```

i have a two list object, which contains a function pointer reference 
which i need to convert in lambda expression. thoes list contains a delegate method , so i have to use  use where bcoz that  a void function

Comment: Instead of `List1[0]` you can use `List1.First()`.  And if you have only 2 items, then instead of `List1[1]` you can use `List1.Last()`.

Comment: But list may grow in future. So need a generic solution

Comment: Then use async ForEach of Linq.